# Issue With Flask Dynamic Routing: routing '/'

Tags: python, flask, dynamic-routing

I am trying to implement dynamic routing with flask. It works except for when the route is '/'. Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    '''create favicon'''
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),
                               'favicon.ico', mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')

@app.route('/<string:page_name>')
def html_page(page_name):
    '''' dynamic routing of template pages'''
    return render_template(page_name)
```

it returns this error: 127.0.0.1 - - [05/Oct/2022 20:45:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `@app.route('/<string:page_name>')` assumes that `page_name` is not an empty string (as it would be for requesting /).

The fix is simple, simply add an extra @app.route and set a default value for page_name:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template,

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    '''create favicon'''
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),
                               'favicon.ico', mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')

@app.route('/', defaults={'page_name': 'index.html'})  # Adds route for /, with page_name='index.html'
@app.route('/<string:page_name>')
def html_page(page_name):
    '''dynamic routing of template pages'''
    return render_template(page_name)
```

You may want to adjust the default value of page_name to be something that makes sense for your application. I am assuming here that you have a template called `index.html`.